# How to copy nested text to clipboard without using a button

Tags: javascript

I have an SQL query on my **HTML** page:

```
<p class="sqlcolor" style="color:black;font-family:Verdana;">
<span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span> 
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">SELECT</span> f.name, f.plz, f.ort, f.strasse<br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">FROM</span> FIRMA f, FIRMA_GEWERKE fg, GEWERKE g<br>
<span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span> 
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">WHERE</span> fg.FG_GEWERKE_ID = g.GEWERKE_ID  <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> f.firma_ID = fg.FG_FIRMA_ID <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> g.gewerke_ID = 
<span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">6</span> <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> fg.active =
<span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">0</span> <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">ORDER BY</span> f.name;
</p>
```

Now what I would like to do is copy the SQL query to the clipboard if a user clicks on it.
I tried to achieve this by using this **Javascript** code:

```
const sql = document.querySelector("p.sqlcolor");

sql.onclick = function() {
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

sql.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.clipboardData) {
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", sql.textContent);
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
  }
});
```

But the text is obviously not copied to the clipboard. I sort of expected that because I am fairly new to Javascript. What would be the best way to achieve what I wanna do with plain Javascript (no jquery please)? Could you please correct my code and/or add some new code to make it work?

*Note:* 
I know how to copy text if I only got one parent element without children (e.g. `<p> some text </p>`). But I want to copy all (nested) text inside this p-class! The problem for me is that the p-class includes span-elements and I think that is the problem why my javascript code does not copy anything to the clipboard. I probably need to go further down but don't know how.

**EDIT:**

I want to add more SQL-Queries to my **HTML**-Page. 
If I add another sql query to the first one...

```
<p class="sqlcolor" style="color:black;font-family:Verdana;">
<span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span> 
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">SELECT</span> f.name, g.bezeichnung<br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">FROM</span> firma f, gewerke g, firma_gewerke fg  <br>
<span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span> 
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">WHERE</span> f.firma_id = fg.fg_firma_id <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> g.gewerke_id = fg.fg_gewerke_id <br>
<span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> f.firma_id =
<span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">493</span>; <br>
```

...I want that the text *depending on the paragraph* I clicked is copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `EventListener` for `click` to the `sql` element and execute the `copy` command within the provided callback. See snippet below.

```js
const sql = document.querySelector("p.sqlcolor");

sql.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.execCommand("copy");
});

sql.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.clipboardData) {
    /* It seems to me that using "innerText" has better output than
     * "textContent", feel free to change it back, if needed.
     */
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", sql.innerText);
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="sqlcolor" style="color:black;font-family:Verdana;">
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">SELECT</span> f.name, f.plz, f.ort, f.strasse<br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">FROM</span> FIRMA f, FIRMA_GEWERKE fg, GEWERKE g<br>
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">WHERE</span> fg.FG_GEWERKE_ID = g.GEWERKE_ID <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> f.firma_ID = fg.FG_FIRMA_ID <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> g.gewerke_ID =
  <span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">6</span> <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> fg.active =
  <span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">0</span> <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">ORDER BY</span> f.name;
</p>
```

**Update for multiple elements:**

In order to be able to apply this approach for multiple elements, you can write a loop which will add an `EventListener` to all DOM elements with `.sqlcolor` class (See snippet below).

```js
// Using querySelectorAll will return a NodeList
const sqlElements = document.querySelectorAll("p.sqlcolor");

/*
 * Using [...sqlElements] as a substitute for "Array.from(sqlElements)"
 * to be able to iterate over the DOM elements
 */
[...sqlElements].forEach(element => {
  // The code below is similar to the one for single element
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });
  element.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      /* It seems to me that using "innerText" has better output than
       * "textContent", feel free to change it back, if needed.
       */
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", element.innerText);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="sqlcolor" style="color:black;font-family:Verdana;">
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">SELECT</span> f.name, f.plz, f.ort, f.strasse<br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">FROM</span> FIRMA f, FIRMA_GEWERKE fg, GEWERKE g<br>
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">WHERE</span> fg.FG_GEWERKE_ID = g.GEWERKE_ID <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> f.firma_ID = fg.FG_FIRMA_ID <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> g.gewerke_ID =
  <span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">6</span> <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> fg.active =
  <span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">0</span> <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">ORDER BY</span> f.name;
</p>

<p class="sqlcolor" style="color:black;font-family:Verdana;">
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">SELECT</span> f.name, g.bezeichnung<br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">FROM</span> firma f, gewerke g, firma_gewerke fg <br>
  <span class="sqlnumbercolor" style="color:"></span>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">WHERE</span> f.firma_id = fg.fg_firma_id <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> g.gewerke_id = fg.fg_gewerke_id <br>
  <span class="sqlkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">AND</span> f.firma_id =
  <span class="sqlstringcolor" style="color:brown">493</span>; <br>
```

Comment: It is working but only for 1 paragraph element (the first one found). If I add another paragraph element with another query, this one won't get copied to the clipboard. See my edit above. I don't want to write identical javascript functions for each of let's say 50 paragraph id's. How do I go around this?